# Confirming one's interest in a project

Tags: phrase-requests

Someone asked me if I am interested in doing a project, I want to answer: "yes!"

Is it ok to say this: (I am going to learn from him in this project more than  really collaborating)

"I like to collaborate in your project"

Comment: The statement as it stands is unidiomatic (i.e. not something a native speaker would ever say). You probably want to phrase it "I *would* like to collaborate *on* your project". Now, if you want to know *why* we say it that way instead of your way, you'd really enjoy participating in our sister site, [ELL.se].

Answer (score 1):

Try possible paraphrases of what you suggested, which will sound more natural to a fluent speaker. Here are a few suggestions: "I would enjoy working with you on a project" or "I would be glad to participate in a project" or simply "I would be extremely interested in working on a project."

Answer (score 1):

You can say,

> I would like to be **involved** in your project.

or,

> I am very interested to **participate** in your project.